# Problem using EventEmitter in NodeJS with 'started' event

Tags: node.js

I am having an issue triggering / responding to an async EventEmitter.emit event.  I am trying to get `this.emit('started',this.files)` to trigger in the find() function, but I only see it happen if I move the event inside the `for (const file of this.files)` loop

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'
import { readFile } from 'fs'

class FindRegex extends EventEmitter {
  constructor (regex) {
    super()
    this.regex = regex
    this.files = []
  }

  addFile (file) {
    this.files.push(file)
    return this
  }

  addFiles(files) {
    for (const file of files) {
      this.addFile(file)
    }
    return this
  }

  find () {
    this.emit('started',this.files)
    for (const file of this.files) {
      readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, content) => {
        if (err) {
          return this.emit('error', err)
        }

        this.emit('fileread', file)

        const match = content.match(this.regex)
        if (match) {
          match.forEach(elem => this.emit('found', file, elem))
        }
      })
    }
    return this
  }
}

let fs = ['fileA.txt','fileB.json']
const findRegexInstance = new FindRegex(/hello \w+/)
findRegexInstance
  .addFiles(fs)
  .find()
  .on('found', (file, match) => console.log(`Matched "${match}" in file ${file}`))
  .on('error', err => console.error(`Error emitted ${err.message}`))
  .on('started', files => console.log(`Started find, files:  ${files}`))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that you call `.find()` BEFORE you've added the event handler for the `started` event yet `find()` sends that event synchronously.  So, you won't have the event handler in place when the event actually occurs.

Some of your other event handlers will work the way you had it because their events are triggered asynchronously, but the synchronous events cause problems.

You could just change the order:

```
findRegexInstance
  .addFiles(fs)
  .on('found', (file, match) => console.log(`Matched "${match}" in file ${file}`))
  .on('error', err => console.error(`Error emitted ${err.message}`))
  .on('started', files => console.log(`Started find, files:  ${files}`))
  .find()
```

You could also use `process.nextTick()` to ensure that no events are triggered synchronously so your event handlers will always be in place before a matching event occurs.

Comment: This works, but I wanted to keep the listener setup as is and call find() in the middle.   I found out I can wrap the 'started' event in a nextTick callback:  
    `nextTick(()=>this.emit('started',this.files))`

Comment: @bkir - Yes, you can do that.  But, you're always "playing with fire" if you attach event handler AFTER you call the function that triggers them.  The only way your original code works is if you make absolutely sure that NO event handlers are ever triggered synchronously.  I would not generally say you should be in the habit of attaching event handlers after the function that makes them happen unless that is documented to always be safe or you are 200% sure you make it always be safe.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  This is just for learning project, but thank you for the heads up!